# Easiest way to inject code to all methods and properties that don't have a custom attribute

Tags: c#, .net, aop, code-injection

There are a a lot of questions and answers around [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) here on Stack Overflow, often mentioning PostSharp and other third-party products. So there seems to be quite a range of AOP optons in the .NET and C# world. But each of those has their restrictions, and after downloading the promising PostSharp <strike>I found in their documentation that 'methods have to be virtual' in order to be able to inject code</strike> (edit: see ChrisWue's answer and my comment - the virtual constraint must have been on one of the contenders, I suppose). I haven't investigated the accuracy of this statement any further, but it's categoricality made me return back to Stack Overflow.

So I'd like to get an answer to this very specific question:

I want to **inject simple** "if (some-condition) Console.WriteLine" style **code to every method and property** (static, sealed, internal, virtual, non-virtual, doesn't matter) **in my project that does not have a custom annotation**, in order to dynamically test my software at run-time. This injected code should not remain in the release build, it is just meant for dynamic testing (thread-related) during development.

What's the easiest way to do this? I stumbled upon [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil), which looks ideal, except that you seem to have to write the code that you want to inject in IL. This isn't a huge problem, it's easy to use Mono.Cecil to get an IL version of code written in C#. But nevertheless, if there was something simpler, ideally even built into .NET (I'm still on .NET 3.5), I'd like to know. **[Update: If the suggested tool is not part of the .NET Framework, it would be nice if it was open-source, like Mono.Cecil, or freely available]**

Comment: Any chance you've since upgraded your solution and have a more modern solution? (E.g. something that leverages Fody or one of it's extensions?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with **Mono.Cecil**. I am still amazed how easy to learn, easy to use, and powerful it is. The almost complete lack of documentation did not change that.

These are the 3 sources of documentation I used:

- [static-method-interception-in-net-with-c-and-monocecil](http://www.codethinked.com/static-method-interception-in-net-with-c-and-monocecil)
- [Migration to 0.9](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Migration)
- the source code itself

The first link provides a very gentle introduction, but as it describes an older version of Cecil - and much has changed in the meantime - the second link was very helpful in translating the introduction to Cecil 0.9. After getting started, the (also not documented) source code was invaluable and answered every question I had - expect perhaps those about the .NET platform in general, but there's tons of books and material on that somewhere online I'm sure.

I can now take a DLL or EXE file, modify it, and write it back to disk. The only thing that I haven't done yet is figuring out how to keep debugging information - file name, line number, etc. currently get lost after writing the DLL or EXE file. My background isn't .NET, so I'm guessing here, and my guess would be that I need to look at `mono.cecil.pdb` to fix that. Somewhere later - it's not that super important for me right now. I'm creating this EXE file, run the application - and it's a complex GUI application, grown over many years with all the baggage you would expect to find in such a piece of, ahem, software - and it checks things and logs errors for me.

Here's the gist of my code:

```
DefaultAssemblyResolver assemblyResolver = new DefaultAssemblyResolver();
// so it won't complain about not finding assemblies sitting in the same directory as the dll/exe we are going to patch
assemblyResolver.AddSearchDirectory(assemblyDirectory);
var readerParameters = new ReaderParameters { AssemblyResolver = assemblyResolver };

AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyFilename, readerParameters);

foreach (var moduleDefinition in assembly.Modules)
{
    foreach (var type in ModuleDefinitionRocks.GetAllTypes(moduleDefinition))
    {
        foreach (var method in type.Methods)
        {
            if (!HasAttribute("MyCustomAttribute", method.method.CustomAttributes)
            {
              ILProcessor ilProcessor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
              ilProcessor.InsertBefore(method.Body.Instructions.First(), ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Call, threadCheckerMethod));
// ...

private static bool HasAttribute(string attributeName, IEnumerable<CustomAttribute> customAttributes)
{
    return GetAttributeByName(attributeName, customAttributes) != null;
}

private static CustomAttribute GetAttributeByName(string attributeName, IEnumerable<CustomAttribute> customAttributes)
{
    foreach (var attribute in customAttributes)
        if (attribute.AttributeType.FullName == attributeName)
            return attribute;
    return null;
}
```

If someone knows an easier way how to get this done, I'm still interested in an answer and I won't mark this as the solution - unless no easier solutions show up.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you got that `methods have to be virtual` from. We use Postsharp to time and log calls to WCF service interface implementations utilizing the `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` to create an attribute we can decorate the classes with. Quick Example:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogMethodCallAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public Type FilterAttributeType { get; set; }

    public LogMethodCallAttribute(Type filterAttributeType)
    {
        FilterAttributeType = filterAttributeType;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (!Proceed(eventArgs)) return;
        Console.WriteLine(GetMethodName(eventArgs));
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (!Proceed(eventArgs)) return;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception at {0}:\n{1}", 
                GetMethodName(eventArgs), eventArgs.Exception));
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (!Proceed(eventArgs)) return;
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} returned {1}", 
                GetMethodName(eventArgs), eventArgs.ReturnValue));
    }
    private string GetMethodName(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}.{1}", eventArgs.Method.DeclaringType, eventArgs.Method.Name);
    }
    private bool Proceed(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
         return Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(eventArgs.Method, FilterAttributeType).Length == 0;
    }
}
```

And then us it like this:

```
 [LogMethodCallAttribute(typeof(MyCustomAttribute))]
 class MyClass
 {
      public class LogMe()
      {
      }

      [MyCustomAttribute]
      public class DoNotLogMe()
      {
      }
 }
```

Works like a charm without having to make any methods virtual in Postsharp 1.5.6. Maybe they have changed it for 2.x but I certainly don't hope so - it would make it way less useful.

**Update**: I'm not sure if you can easily convince Postsharp to only inject code into certain methods based on with which attributes they are decorated. If you look at [this tutorial](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-3-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-2.aspx) it only shows ways of filtering on type and method names. We have solved this by passing the type we want to check on into the attribute and then in `OnEntry` you can use reflection to look for the attributes and decide whether to log or not. The result of that is cached so you only have to do it on the first call.

I adjusted the code above to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: Chris, you're right, I got that confused. What turned me off though was on [http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation] where it says: "To make this class an aspect, it must derive from an aspect parent class defined by Postsharp". But of course this makes sense, now reading carefully. Only aspects need to derive bla-bla, not the methods that want to be "aspectized". However, I want to inject code to all methods that DO NOT have a certain attribute.

Comment: @Eugene: I extended my answer to cover that

Comment: I don't quite understand how "passing the type we want to check" solves the "inject code into everything (except if annotated with my custom attribute)" problem. Do you have an example? I want to all types (minus a few), so I don't know what types it will be.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I got it. This is indeed simple and easy - if nothing easier shows up (I'm still waiting for something that is part of the .net framework or so), I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Chris, I just looked at the 2nd code snippet again - does this mean I have to annotate every class with  [LogMethodCallAttribute(typeof(MyCustomAttribute))]? That would mean I'd have to touch all classes for this to work, including those that don't have annotated methods (and are thus code injection targets). I don't want to do that. Or do I only have to annotate classes when I want to annotate methods inside that class? I don't understand why I have to annotate at the class level at all, I only want to annotate methods.

Comment: @Eugene: No, you can also apply the attribute to the whole assembly. Have a look at the sharpcrafters tutorial: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-3-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-2.aspx

Comment: OK, so I would add one attribute at the assembly level, and my custom attribute would kind of override that attribute? That would work for me.