# Common code for multiple properties

Tags: c#, properties

We have a helper function to remove html tags from the string that we want to apply to few properties of our classes like Name, Firstname, Comments etc.

So for that what I am doing right now is removing html tags before assigning value to the property like this

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _dalObj.Name; }
    set { _dalObj.Name = Helper.StripHTML(value); }
}
```

This is working fine!

But I am looking for some better and centralized way to do this rather than applying it to all the properties setter.

So that I will write this code once somewhere centrally and then will mark the properties (may be by custom data annotation or registering them somewhere or using reflection) and those properties will be picked automatically and this code will be applied to there setter.

Is there any way to achieve this or what I am doing is right?

Comment: Are you using any framework and.. what programming language is this?

Comment: @StephenKing - Language is C# and we are not using any framework as such. But yes we do have a structure that all our business classes follow. There is an abstract class that all our business class inherits. So if I add anything in the abstract class it will apply to all the inserts and updates of all the business classes.

Comment: Side note: usually one expects property to retain value you set to it: `foo.Name = x; Assert.AreEqual(x, foo.Name)`... Breaking this lead to confusion and bugs in code. While it is not going to help your particular problem consider changing `set` calls to methods.

Comment: You've obviously searched for existing questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672080/easiest-way-to-inject-code-to-all-methods-and-properties-that-dont-have-a-custo, so consider actually providing results of your research in the post so it is clear what you've already considered and reasons for rejection.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - You are right!
But changing set calls to methods will be a huge change :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always encode it as part of your types!

`_dalObj` could be some type which declares name as such:

`private NoHtmlString _name = ""`

with the class `NoHtmlString` looking something like this:

```
public class NoHtmlString
{
    private readonly string _value;

    private NoHtmlString(string str)
    {
        _value = str;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(NoHtmlString noHtmlString)
    {
        return noHtmlString._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator NoHtmlString(string someString)
    {
        return new NoHtmlString(StringHelpers.StripHtml(someString));
    }
}
```

This way your outer accessing layers could just do the following:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _dalObj.Name; }
    set { _dalObj.Name = value; }
}
```

You get the benefit of having something you can implicitly use as a string, but with the guarantee that it will always be stripped of the HTML.

As others have mentioned, this could be achieved using Aspect-Oriented Programming as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like a code smell, that the property will have a different value than the one that was set.

I would suggest to store the value as it is, and implement in the abstract base class a `Sanitize()` method, which will go trough all those properties and strip the html, it can be done trough reflection for exploring properties to sanitize (e.g. those with some attribute), or it can be an abstract method implemented by each class to sanitize the proper properties.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to do some [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

One AOP tool that you can use with C# is [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/). You can use it to create an Aspect, e.g. HtmlStripperAspect and then apply it to your properties.

For example, you would have something like this:

```
[HtmlStripperAspect]
public string Name
{
    get { return _dalObj.Name; }
    set { _dalObj.Name = value; }
}
```

where HtmlStripperAspect is a centralized class that you create with the help of PostSharp and inside such class you call your Helper.StripHTML method.

You can apply the aspect also on the class, namespace, or assembly level if you don't want to decorate all your properties with HtmlStripperAspect.

Take a look at [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) documentation on how exactly this is done.

PostSharp is a compile-time AOP tool, it injects IL code into your assemblies at compile time. If you don't like this, there are run-time AOP tools such as [Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/).